# Hash in Ruby & Convert python to ruby

Tags: python, ruby, dictionary

I am using Hash in Ruby, just check whether a certain word is in the “pairs” class and replace them. Initially I code in python and want to convert it into ruby that I am not familiar with. Here is the ruby code I wrote.

```
import sys

pairs = {'butter' => 'flies', 'cheese' => 'wheel', 'milk'=> 'expensive'}

for line in sys.stdin:
    line_words = line.split(" ")
    for word in line_words:
      if word in pairs
        line = line.gsub!(word, pairs[word])

puts line
```

It shows the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected kIN, expecting kTHEN or ':' or '\n' or ';'
      if word in pairs
                ^
```

While below is the original python script which is right:

```
import sys

pairs = dict()

pairs = {'butter': 'flies', 'cheese': 'wheel', 'milk': 'expensive'}

for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.strip()
  line_words = line.split(" ")
  for word in line_words:
    if word in pairs:
      line = line.replace(word ,pairs[word])

print line
```

Is it because of "import sys" or “Indentation”？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pairs = {'butter' => 'flies', 'cheese' => 'wheel', 'milk'=> 'expensive'}

line = ARGV.join(' ').split(' ').map do |word|
  pairs.include?(word) ? pairs[word] : word
end.join(" ")

puts line
```

This will loop over each item passed to the script and return the word or the replacement word, joined by a space.

Comment: Thanks kardeiz! What is the type of the line that Ruby "puts",is it an array?Since it print out single word by lines I wonder if they split the line twice. If I still want to puts out a whole line, what should I do? line.join(" ") cannot solve the problem.

Comment: Hi!I found a difference when I put quotation marks in input. For example, when I try to input "this is butter", it print "this is butter". If it is"'this is butter'", the output will be "this is flies". What cause the difference? And when I put the code on server, there is error called " undefined method `map' for "this is butter":String (NoMethodError)".

Comment: I slightly modified the script so that you can pass the string to be converted either as a sequence of arguments or as one (wrapped in quotes): `ARGV.join(' ').split(' ')`, which joins the arg array with a space, then splits on spaces. I'm not sure about your second issue: what is the context in which the script is being called? Your error indicates that `ARGV` is being interpreted as a string, but `ARGV` should always be an array (even if empty).

Comment: Yes! Actually the content is ARGV[2], so i think it is a string?

Answer (score 0):

`for` is generally not used in Ruby, as it's got some unusual scoping.

Here's how I would write it:

```
pairs = { "butter" => "flies", "cheese" => "wheel", "milk" => "expensive" }
until $stdin.eof?
  line = $stdin.gets
  pairs.each do |from, to|
    line = line.gsub(from, to)
  end

  line
end
```

`import` doesn't exist in Ruby, so that shouldn't be there. You also have to "close" each block with `end` in Ruby, indentation alone isn't enough (indentation doesn't mean anything to Ruby, although you should still keep it for readability).